# DAX measure to Extract the Max Date for a particular Value in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

| status_Id | signal_name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pos | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 2 | supplier | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 3 | customer | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 4 | warehouse | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 5 | Movement | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 6 | shipment | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 7 | trackers | 2/5/2024 17:28 |
| 8 | pos | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 9 | supplier | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 10 | customer | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 11 | warehouse | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 12 | Movement | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 13 | shipment | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 14 | trackers | 2/6/2024 16:06 |
| 15 | pos | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 16 | supplier | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 17 | customer | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 18 | warehouse | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 19 | Movement | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 20 | shipment | 2/7/2024 16:06 |
| 21 | trackers | 2/7/2024 16:06 |

For a Particular Line Item, I want to extract the **MAX** date for that particular signal_name.

for **Movement** I need **2/7/2024**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
Latest Date = 
  var d = 
    CALCULATE(
      LASTDATE('YourTable'[date]),
      ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[signal_name])
    )
  return DATEVALUE(d)
```